# Passing parameters via url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I pass parameters to a Rails application using a normal web url?

For instance if I have..

http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/create/list[name]=Paul&list[age]=39&list[tag]=misc

So I have created a controller called lists and I want to pass a name, age and a tag..

In my example I am passing..

name = Paul
age = 39
tag = misc

My example I pasted above says that the item was created but the item it adds has empty data, suggesting my formatting isn't correct.

Could anyone tell me how I structure the url above to pass the parameters correctly?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: how the heck are you posting to 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: hmm thats the default address I get told to connect to when I run script/server, I also tried localhost:3000 but still get the same problems, this is all been tested locally at the moment

Answer (score 3):

By default, Rails's RESTful routing prohibits the `create` action via the `GET` (regular url) protocol. For your specific example, you would need to add this route to your config/routes.rb file:

```
map.create_list 'list/create', :controller => 'lists', :action => 'create', :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

This adds a route `create_list_path` or `create_list_url` that is accessible via `GET` for links, etc. The url used to create a list directly would be:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/create?list[name]=Paul&list[age]=39&list[tag]=misc
```

Also note that if you are getting errors about invalid authenticity tokens, you may need to add this line to your controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
```

For more general cases, you configure routes similarly and forms as follows:

You need to specify `:method => 'get'` in your `form_tag`.

This is discussed in the [Ruby on Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) guide (search for "A Generic Search Form").

The basic code given that should get you started is

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

generates

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <label for="q">Search for:</label>
  <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

which `GET`s the url: `http://my.server/search?q={query input}&commit=Search`.

Comment: I don't really have my own form at this stage, other than what the scaffold would have generated

Comment: In the scaffold-generated form you should be able to add `:method => 'get'` to put the parameters in the url.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this without forms, I ultimately want to be able to just call the url passing a few parameters so it wont use forms at all

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct url for your GET request? `http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/create/list[name]=Paul&list[age]=39&list[tag]=misc` should be `http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/create?list[name]=Paul&list[age]=39&list[tag]=misc`.

Comment: This is part of the problem and what i'm trying to figure out with all this, I don't know what the correct url should be.
The url I posted creates an empty entry in the db so i'm guessing its wrong somewhere.
How do I find out what the correct url should be?

Comment: I misread your last post and tried your version of the url but got the error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show Couldn't find List with ID=create

Comment: Ah, okay. That means it's a problem with your routing? Are you using rails 2 or 3? I'll update my answer with the route you need once I know.

Comment: Okay, I have added the route you need to access the create action with a get request. Try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: I added your route but am still getting exactly the same error :(